# How to set unicode characters to database

Tags: mysql, unicode

I am working on twitter API in java I want to save search tweets in mysql database,I have changed default encoding type of table  to utf-8 and collate to utf8_unicode_ci,also for column for which I am getting unicode values I have set default encoding type of  to utf-8 
and collate to utf8_unicode_ci. But stiil I am gettin data truncated for column,my data is not saved properly.
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your table definition?

Comment: Which Mysql Version do you use?

Comment: Have you change the values in your config file?

Comment: I am using mysql server 5

Comment: Relevant article: http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the [Connection Character Sets and Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) too using:

```
SET NAMES 'charset_name' [COLLATE 'collation_name']
```

and

```
SET CHARACTER SET charset_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old but since I was looking into the same issue today I stumbled into your question.
Since twitter supports emoticons aka Emoji you will have to switch to utf8mb4 instead of utf8. In a nutshell turns out MySQL’s utf8 charset only partially implements proper UTF-8 encoding. It can only store UTF-8-encoded symbols that consist of one to three bytes; encoded symbols that take up four bytes aren’t supported!
Since astral symbols (whose code points range from U+010000 to U+10FFFF) each consist of four bytes in UTF-8, you cannot store them using MySQL’s utf8 implementation.
Here is a [link](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4) to a tutorial discussing the matter and detaily explains how to do the conversion to utf8mb4.